# .NET assembly version - what's the difference (based on System.Web.Mvc experience)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

I have opened MVC3 project in Visual Studio 2013 and since VS2013 supports MVC4+ out of the box I had two options:

1. download MVC3 DLL (System.Web.Mvc 3.0.X.X) into my project
2. add references to MVC4 DLL (System.Web.Mvc 4.0.X.X) and fix Web.config entries

I would like to understand couple of things:

- is the assembly version equivalent to MVC framework version (new features available in MVC4 are imported with the newer version of assembly etc.)
- why is the package (f.e. on NuGet) called System.AspNet.Mvc and the assembly is known as System.Web.Mvc (same as namespace)

Same goes for Razor, WebPages, Helpers etc.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"why is the package (f.e. on NuGet) called System.AspNet.Mvc and the assembly is known as System.Web.Mvc (same as namespace)"

This is likely because the package contains many assemblies besides System.Web.Mvc.  Since the recommended approach is package per DLL, and this package falls outside of that common practice, then so not to mislead you to think the package is only that one DLL, they give it a distinct name.

It may also help distinguish it from other potentially similarly named MVC frameworks.  We often refer to it with fellow C# coders as "MVC", but that is a pretty generic architecture pattern.  To be more specific it is ASP.NET MVC.

"is the assembly version equivalent to MVC framework version (new features available in MVC4 are imported with the newer version of assembly etc.)"

Yes, if you get the MVC 4 package, then you will have the new features with that version.